# Launching trackPageview google analytics from serverside?

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

Is that possible to launch this code from server side?
for example I want to run a cron every X minutes.
that will check XYZ.
and if its true it will launch an event to google analytics exactly like this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '03_insert_name.php']);
         </script>
```

Is that even possible? if so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data to Google Analytics server side then you should use the Measurement Protocol.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/